# Get element inside class with selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I'm currently working on a web **scraping** program to get the price from a steam game with selenium. The problem is that I can't find the way to get the "data-price-final", can you help me please?

```
<div class="game_purchase_price price" data-price-final="1150000">
CLP$ 11.500</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use get_attribute on the attribute in question.

```
value=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='game_purchase_price price']").get_attribute("data-price-final")
print(value)
```